# Optimal databasesystem for filters

Tags: mysql, performance, mongodb, objectdatasource, relation

I am building a website that implements filters that can be applied to a dataset. Allow me to explain these filters. In this case it will be a website with houses.

```
Number of rooms:
    2 or less ( 2271 )
    3 or more ( 4283 )
    4 or more ( 2223 )
    5 or more ( 1213 )

Price range
    More then {fill in number}
    Less then {fill in number}

Type
    For sale ( 2938 )
    For rent ( 1029 )
```

You see it more frequently these days. It would be a total of about 7 filters.

Now I am not sure what kind of database I should use. There will be about 10000 entities and daily changes (about 1% of the dataset). The two that I am considering are:

**[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) Object Oriented**

First of all, I am new to these -so called- object oriented databases. But I have heard some good stories about them. They are scheme less and likely very fast at the job.

**[MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) Relational database**

I have used the MySQL before in this situations, the performance was acceptable. I used a [EAV-Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAV) that makes the database more dynamic. I used a InnoDB engine with relations to maintain the integrity.

The problem is that when I use multiple filters the subqueries stack up, this happens when I calculate the number of posibilities when u select the filter.

What do think about the performance in this situation, what dbms would perform better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either.
if u use a denormalized table in mysql (i.e. no joins) it is similar to an object in mongoDB although harder to query.
So, if can have your data de-normalized in a sensible way, go with Mongo  Otherwise, RDBMS.

Comment: The problem is that some houses are for sale and other houses are for rent, for example. So these houses have different attributes. Denormalization would be a option, but I would be rather slow I think.

Comment: My intuition on this would be to use OO/NoSQL database.

Answer (score 1):

With 10,000 records, the performance should be decent in MySQL.  Since you are already familiar with MySQL, I will recommend that you use that.  You can try `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-modifiers.html) to get the job done with just one query.  MySQL as well as your client will need to do some extra work, but I think it will be offset by the reduction in the number of queries.